# Umlauts encoding in ImpEx

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In my project,there are some German Umlauts like ä, ö, ü.When these are imported as a part of a name(like aüa),it is replaced via a weird ? symbol.This issue is intermittent on several releases in higher environment.How to sort this issue out?

Comment: did you try change them with unicode?

Comment: Yes,then the unicode itself gets displayed.

Comment: If you want help, please provide the faulty impex and describe where exactly the rendering fails.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to see if the UTF-8 format is set for the file?
Right click on the file in the Package Explorer view and press Preferencies.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- make sure your impex file is UTF-8 encoded
- make sure your JVM encoding for the hybris server is set to UTF-8 (property `tomcat.generaloptions=... -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...`
- make sure your database stores UTF-8 correctly (all tables have correct encoding configured)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ä = "&auml;"
Überblick => &Uuml;berblick
```